# any suggestions on how to overcome ORA-00937?

Tags: sql, ora-00937

```
select s.S_FIRST||' '||s.S_LAST, sum(c.CREDITS) from enrollment e,student s,course c
where s.s_id=e.S_ID
and c.COURSE_NO=e.C_SEC_ID
group by s.S_ID
having sum(c.credits)>12 order by s.s_id;

Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
```

It keeps coming back with an error, any suggestions ?

thanks for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

Actually there were a couple issues in the SQL.  Try this...

```
select s.s_id, s.S_FIRST||' '||s.S_LAST name, sum(c.CREDITS) sum_credits
from enrollment e,student s,course c
where s.s_id=e.S_ID
and c.COURSE_NO=e.C_SEC_ID
group by 1, 2
having sum(c.credits) > 12 
order by s.s_id;
```

You must group by all nonaggregate fields. Also I don't think you can order on a field not in your query (and hence would also need to be in the select list and group by).  The error in the docs is [ORA-00937](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e900.htm#1000563).

Based on your invalid number comments, I think your join is wrong on course_no or maybe credits isn't a number or something, though.

Answer (score 0):

You meed to include all your columns in select list to group by. See here http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00979_not_a_group_by_expression.htm

From documentation

> Cause: The GROUP BY clause does not contain all the expressions in the
>   SELECT clause. SELECT expressions that are not included in a group
>   function, such as AVG, COUNT, MAX, MIN, SUM, STDDEV, or VARIANCE, must
>   be listed in the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Action: Include in the GROUP BY clause all SELECT expressions that are
>   not group function arguments

Remedy, include all columns in select list to your `group by` clause. change your query like

```
select s.S_FIRST||' '||s.S_LAST as fullname, s.s_id, 
sum(c.CREDITS) as total_credit from enrollment e,
student s,course c
where s.s_id=e.S_ID
and c.COURSE_NO=e.C_SEC_ID
group by s.S_FIRST||' '||s.S_LAST
having total_credit > 12 
order by s.s_id;
```

Per Oracle spec error `ORA-01722` means `The attempted conversion of a character string to a number failed because the character string was not a valid numeric literal.`

Make sure all your fields are of INT type or same type. IS `c.CREDITS` INT type?

are `s.s_id` and `e.S_ID` of same type?

are `c.COURSE_NO` and `e.C_SEC_ID` of same type?

Comment: Hey bro, it came back with this Error report: SQL Error: ORA-01722: invalid number 01722. 00000 - "invalid number"